# Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file

Tags: java, utf-8

I am trying to make a Java applet for my website.
I'm having major issues getting it to work.

I get this error: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file

You can see this error here: http://www.test.world2build.com/Game/Play.aspx

The code for this applet can be found here:

http://www.test.world2build.com/Game/Applet.txt

This applet was exported as a Jar in Eclipse, and uploaded to my website via CoffeeCup Direct FTP.

Comment: This happened to me once. I started to compile a very large project and immediately locked the computer. When I returned, the compilation task was done but then started to get this error when running the app. I recompiled again without locking the computer and worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(EDIT: The jar file on the server has now changed...)

It's hard to help without *any* background, code etc.

Given that the jar file itself is invalid (I've just downloaded it and tried to open it) I suspect you did something like uploading it to your hosting provider in ASCII instead of BINARY mode.

If my psychic debugging powers have failed this time (and this was really stretching them) I strongly suggest you give us more information - importantly:

- How did you build your jar file?
- Does your jar file work locally?
- How have you uploaded it to your hosting provider?

Looking at the jar file with a hex editor, it appears to have some Java source code in it *in plain text - uncompressed* which would be somewhat odd in a jar file. It also doesn't open as a valid zip file...

Comment: Hi... I am very new to Java. I uploaded it via CoffeeCup Direct FTP. I do not know how to tell if the jar works locally. I suppose you mean I can run it? If so, I click it and nothing happens.

Comment: @BaileyMcAfee: You can use [AppletViewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) - but how did you create the jar file to start with? You've given us almost *no* information here...

Comment: I developed this program in Eclipse, and exported it as a Jar. I just uploaded the jar via cPanel FTP, and now it shows an error saying "1"

Comment: @BaileyMcAfee: Well, it's hard to know exactly where things have gone wrong, but your jar file is invalid. What's its size on your local machine?

Comment: The size is 11.3 KB, 12.0 KB on disk.

Comment: @BaileyMcAfee: Ah, this time it's a valid jar file... and you're not getting the error that the title describes, either. What did you change?

Comment: I uploaded it in a different way -- directly from Apache's cPanel FTP. Now the error is different... just says '1'

Comment: @BaileyMcAfee: I'm not even seeing the "1". So you now have a completely different problem, presumably due to broken code. I suggest you start with a *simpler* applet and build up from there. You might as well delete this question, too, as the original problem is explained (as per my guess) by a broken upload.

Comment: What exactly do you see, then?

Comment: @BaileyMcAfee: Nothing at all - switching to the tab (in Chrome) doesn't even update the screen, which is pretty odd. In IE it locks with the Java logo.

Comment: @BaileyMcAfee: I suspect the problem is your use of `wait()` which is blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue while running command `gradle clean build` in my spring boot project. I have just restarted my laptop. Then problem solved!.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 hours of deleting, commenting, undoing stuff. Restarting Android studio, deleting java files from control panel and restoring defaults, invalidating caches, cleaning project etc...

One restart of the system solved this. I recommend that you save yourself from all this, hit the restart button, and then search for witches.

Answer (score 0):

illegal utf8 in constant pool class format error....
this java error tired me. ı could not solve it for several weeks in mac. finally found the way mac>preferences>java>genral>settings>delete files>default settings was the solution

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when a ubuntu laptop powered down during n SBT project compile in IntelliJ.

"Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/DenseMatrix"

The solution was to restart the laptop then do a invalidate/cache restart.