# Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file error in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to run a file (java main, cucumber feature, junit test) I get the following error in IntelliJ Idea:

```
    Information:15/05/2015 14:57 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1s 134ms
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassFormatError) Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file org/jetbrains/jps/model/serialization/java/JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension$JavaProjectExtensionSerializer
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file org/jetbrains/jps/model/serialization/java/JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension$JavaProjectExtensionSerializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.java.JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension.getProjectExtensionSerializers(JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:265)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:242)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I tried restarting the IDE, importing the project again but nothing worked. Did anyone experience this error before ?

Comment: The error message is complaining that the class file for class `org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.java.JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension.JavaProjectExtensionSerializer` is invalid.  IntelliJ might or might not be correct about that, but your options fall into two categories: (1) replace the class file, and (2) update / replace the Java compiler / JVM.

Comment: Your installation may now be corrupted. On eclipse someone got this tho, so there may be an equivalent for idea(dig deep in the settings) http://ilgthegeek.livius.net/2014/09/07/java-illegal-utf8-string-constant-pool-class-file/ . Some also suggested it may be to jdk version changes

Comment: Well you're not the first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673511/illegal-utf8-string-in-constant-pool-in-class-file

Comment: Did you try menu item `File / Invalidate Caches`.

Comment: @JoopEggen Just tried it. Ddidn't work.

Comment: Did you switch encodings to UTF-8? I imagine then getting a java source with a Unicode string literal with wrong encoding compiled as UTF-8. A non-strict compiler might produce a wrong .class file.

Comment: @JoopEggen No, I even tried to create a new project with a simple HelloWorld console application. I got the same error.

Comment: Yes, it actually complains on class JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension$JavaProjectExtensionSerializer. Did you switch from Java version 7 to 8? Reinstalling IDEA?

Comment: This error comes when the .class file is edited using text editors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by deleting `.IntelliJIdea` folder and reimporting the project.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I'm on windows, the folder which needs to be deleted is on my installation c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\index\

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer for those who also experience this issue not only in IntelliJ but also with maven builds outside IntelliJ. Reinstalling the JDK was the only solution that worked for me.